# Able to read HealthKit data through HKObserverQuery even after I disabled the permission in the Health App. Is this a bug?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkobserverquery

I am working on an app that has an `HKObserverQuery` that starts immediately when the view is loaded. That `HKObserverQuery` calls to a function that executes an `HKStatisticsQuery` that can retrieve the sum of all the `step count` for today.

When I started the App. I allowed the App to read the counts. Total `step count` where available.

After a few mins. I decided to block the permission to read the `step count` count.

When I come back to the app, it still updates itself with the new `step count` counts.

Is this some bug? should the app be able to read new data even when it does not have permission to access the `HealthKit`.

Comment: Did you confirm that the switch you disabled in when you blocked permission is still turned off if you look at the app's permissions again?

Comment: Yes. Its is disabled, and my app is still able to detect changes.